# Fetching the Javascript Variable and pass as a parameter in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am not able to fetch the value of the javascript variable and pass it in the ajax call as a parameter.

```html
<select id="mySelect" onblur="updateERPfunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
```

```js
function updateERPfunction() {
  var my_val= document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  alert(my_val);
 }
```

I want to use the value of my_val in another onfocus function:

```
 <input name="MappingId" onfocus="backgroundColorToWhite('MappingId_${efField.efMappingId}'); bindKeyDownEvent(my_val); />
```

Please help me in fetching the `my_val` value from JS function to JSP.

Comment: If you want to do this using jQuery (as you've tagged it) check the `data` parameter in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax. Note that your `onfocus` is missing a closing quote. Finally, just FYI, to 'fetch' something means that you want to get it from somewhere. In this case it seems that you instead want to 'send' the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps (assuming you don't mind jquery) :

```
 <select id="mySelect" onblur="updateERPfunction()">
 <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
 <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

 <input name="MappingId"  />


$(document).ready(function() {
    var my_val = '';
  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
       my_val = $(this).val();
      // feel free to use ajax if required: 
      // $.post('server url', {}, function(data) {
      //       my_val = data.my_val;
      // });
  })

  $('[name="MappingId"]').focus(function()  {
    alert(my_val)
    $(this).blur();
  });
});
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t8vsm17n/